# write list of dataframes to multiple excel files

Tags: r, excel, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes. Conveniently named:

```
list.df
```

and the objects, which are dataframes, are just this:

```
list.df[[1]]  
list.df[[2]]  
list.df[[3]]
```

I am trying to use lapply to write each of the list.df objects to a seperate excel sheet.

I can't use the xlsx library because my workplace disables everything Java...
so I've been trying write_xlsx.

I've tried the following:

```
lapply(names(list.df), 
              function (x) write_xlsx(list.df[[x]], file=paste(x, "xlsx", sep=".")))
```

But nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is `all.list3` changed to `df.daily`?  Based on the example, `lapply(names(list.df), function(x) write_xlsx(list.df[[x]], file = paste0(x, ".xlsx")))`

Comment: typo. but it is as you have provided "Based on the example". still nothing happens. just I see list() in the console

Comment: So, you are not finding any files in the directory?

Comment: Correct. The code doesn't write anything to the directory.

Comment: You said `I can't use the xlsx library because my workplace disables everything Java.`  and `write_xlsx` is from `xlsx`?  right.  If the `rJava` is not correctly installed, it won't work

Comment: nope, from writexl

Comment: Can you try to give a specific path? `lapply(names(list_df), function(x) write_xlsx(list_df[[x]], paste0("/Users/username/Downloads/", x, ".xlsx")))` ?

Answer (score 4):

i think this might help you

```
require(openxlsx)
available_dfs<- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)))]

list_of_datasets <- list("Name of DataSheet1" = dataframe1, "Name of Datasheet2" = dataframe2)
write.xlsx(list_of_datasets, file = "writeXLSX2.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 4):

For `write_xlsx` from `writexl`, there is no `file` argument.  It is the `path` argument

```
library(writexl)
lapply(names(list.df), 
          function (x) write_xlsx(list.df[[x]], path=paste(x, "xlsx", sep=".")))
```

-output directory with files

[image]

#### data

```
list.df <-  list(A = structure(list(X1 = c("a", "d", "g", "j"), X2 = 1:4, 
    X3 = c("b", "e", "h", "k"), X4 = c("c", "f", "i", "l")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), B = structure(list(X1 = c("a", "d", "g", "j"), X2 = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), X3 = c("b", "e", "h", "k"), X4 = c("c", "f", "i", 
"l")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)), C = structure(list(
    X1 = c("a", "d", "g", "j"), X2 = 1:4, X3 = c("b", "e", "h", 
    "k"), X4 = c("c", "f", "i", "l")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```